# Align stacked equation in beamer

Tags: beamer, equations, align, arrays

I am looking for a way to align these stacked equations in beamer frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usetheme{CambridgeUS}  
    \usecolortheme{beaver}
    \usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Basic Game}

\textbf{Payoffs}   
     \[\pi_{w} = \left\{
     \begin{array}{@{}l@{\medspace}l}
            w & \hspace{2em} \text{if employed}\\
            0 & \hspace{2em} \text{otherwise}\\
     \end{array}
   \right. \]\\
   
    \[\pi_{F} = \left\{
     \begin{array}{@{}l@{\medspace}l}
             100 L - \sum_{i=1}^{m} w_{i} & \hspace{2em} \text{if employing}\\
            0 & \hspace{2em} \text{otherwise}\\
     \end{array}
   \right.
\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It looks like this.

[image: View]

Comment: How exactl should the output look like?

Comment: The pi's should be vertically aligned, I don't care whether centered or everything aligned to the left of the frame.

Comment: You could place both equations inside of an `align*` environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would employ an `align*` environment to align the `=` symbols and two `dcases*` environments (code provided by the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package) to spell out the conditions. Observe that the contents of `dcases` and `dcases*` environments are rendered in displaymath mode automatically; that's likely desirable for material that's presented visually.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usetheme{CambridgeUS}  
    \usecolortheme{beaver}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{mathtools} % for 'dcases*' env.
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Basic Game}
\textbf{Payoffs}  
\begin{align*} 
\pi_{w} &= 
\begin{dcases*}
   w & if employed\\
   0 & otherwise
\end{dcases*} \\[1ex] % '[1ex]' for a bit more vertical separation
\pi_{F}^{} &= 
\begin{dcases*}
   100 L - \sum_{i=1}^{m} w_{i} & if employing\\
   0  & otherwise
\end{dcases*}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum to address the OP's follow-up question*: There are almost certainly several ways to achieve the supplemental formatting task. One way would involve using a `\parbox`, where the width of the parbox is derived from the widest cell in the second `dcases*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usetheme{CambridgeUS}  
    \usecolortheme{beaver}
    \usepackage{array,mathtools} 
    %% new code, for follow-up query:
    \newlength{\mylen}
    \settowidth{\mylen}{$\displaystyle 100 L - \sum_{i=1}^{m} w_{i}$}
    \newcommand\mybox[1]{\parbox{\mylen}{\raggedright$\displaystyle #1$}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Basic Game}
\textbf{Payoffs}  
\begin{align*} 
\pi_{w} &= 
\begin{dcases*}
   \mybox{w} & if employed\\ % <-- note: "\mybox{w}" rather than "w"
   0 & otherwise
\end{dcases*} \\[1ex] % '[1ex]' for a bit more vertical separation
\pi_{F}^{} &= 
\begin{dcases*}
   100 L - \sum_{i=1}^{m} w_{i} & if employing\\
   0  & otherwise
\end{dcases*}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, just thinking about this now. Would it also be possible to align the text, i.e. increase the horizontal space between equation and text for the upper equation? That was originally the reason to use this complicated structure.

Comment: @Papayapap - Please see the addendum I posted.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usetheme{CambridgeUS}  
    \usecolortheme{beaver}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Basic Game}
\textbf{Payoffs}   
  \begin{align*}
    \pi_{w} &= \begin{cases} 
                  w & \text{if employed}\\
                  0 & \text{otherwise}
                \end{cases} \\
    \pi_{F} &= \begin{cases} 
                  100 L - \sum_{i=1}^{m} w_{i} & \text{if employing}\\
                  0 & \text{otherwise}
                \end{cases} 
  \end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, just thinking about this now. Would it also be possible to align the text, i.e. increase the horizontal space between equation and text for the upper equation? That was originally the reason to use this complicated structure.